# How to search for files on phone sdcard or else where

Tags: android, search, file, filesystems, file-extension

I want to search for files on the users mobile with specific extensions.

I tried searching but could not find any direct API's.

Is there a specific API's or is there tedious way of achieving the same.
Or is there a mechanism to call linux calls for find or something similar

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the user's SD card via `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`, which you can then traverse to find what you need.

Comment: thats a pretty sad way of searching, especially if u think android created by google

Comment: If you are specifically looking for media files -- which, in your extremely short question, you didn't specify -- try the `MediaStore` content provider. I don't know how readily you can use it to search by file extension, though.

Answer (score 4):

```
   boolean isSDPresent = Environment.getExternalStorageState()
            .equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);

    if (isSDPresent) {
        File file[] = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().listFiles();
        if (file != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
                file[i].getAbsolutePath();
            }
        }
    }
```

Traverse `file[]` for the required file